# Buildfire: Debugging on IOS Test Flight

Tags: buildfire

I can't seem to figure out why my plugin works fine on the Web App mode, versus the IOS Test Flight.
It seems like an angularjs dependency is not loading correctly, but I have no way of knowing.

Comment: For clarification, your plugin is using AngualrJS, right? If so are you sure you're using a relative path to reference it? A plugin is shipped to 3 different environments between PWA, iOS, and Android all with different file systems and different folders. For example, the device only gets the widget folder. So if your widget relies on a resource located outside the widget folder it will work on web but not the device.

Comment: Yes, AngularJS. Currently, all of the dependencies I have are using a CDN url. There are no resources in the content folder that are used in widget.

Comment: That will slow down your plugin and it wont work in offline mode. Are you using a TLS/SSL (HTTPS) to serve up your dependencies?

Comment: yes https. I am also using angular material with angularjs

Comment: Have you tried loading them locally?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your app/plugin situation is precisely. However, a good place to start would be here https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/App-Developer-Mode this will allow you to test your code live on the device without publishing. It hijacks the plugin and loads your localhost version so that you can test on the fly changes.

Also, you may want to try shipping logs with http://debug.buildfire.com this will allow you to read console logs remotely

Comment: I tried debugging by shipping logs, and I still didn't get any console logs that usually log when testing in the Buildfire dashboard.

Comment: Have you tried hijacking the plugin with your local server? This lets you test immediately your code on the device. You even do crude hacks like alerts if you need to without shipping the code to production.